# Interpreting y-axis of partial dependence plots produced by pdp package

Tags: r, plot

Using `caret::train()` I have created a boosted regression tree (method = gbm) and gotten an output of relative influence for my predictor variables.

I now want to know the direction of influence for the top predictors, so have completed partial dependence plots for these variables however I am not sure how to interpret the y-axis.

I want the y-axis to simply represent my response variable which is binomial (presence/absence) so that I can extrapolate whether a close or far distance from water is influencing presence.

Example of partial dependance plot for predictor variable distance to water.

[image: Example of partial dependance plot for predictor variable distance to water]

Answer (score 2):

The y-axis of a partial dependence plot for regression represents the marginal impact of the independent variable to the dependent variable. E.g. if the line is at 0, then for that value of the independent variable, there is 0 impact to the dependent variable. It does not represent the predicted value or relative impact of this variable to other variables. However, you can deduce relative impact by plotting multiple partial dependence plots side by side for multiple independent variables and share the y-axis.

Comment: As far as I understood the question was related to a classification problem rather than a regression.

Comment: Yes, PDP plots work with either one. Its just a marginal dependence of feature X on the label. The distribution of the label doesnt affect the technique.

Answer (score 1):

If you fit your model with probabilities, with the package pdp you can plot partial dependence plots and specify the parameter "prob" to `TRUE`, then the partial dependence will be returned on the probability scale instead of centred logit ([red pdp documentaion](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdp/vignettes/pdp-intro.pdf)). Maybe this helps you interpret the plot. Example:

```
pdp::partial(fit, "Dist_Water, type = "classification", which.class = "presence", prob = TRUE, rug = T, plot = T)
```

Or extracting the data and using ggplot2 to plot (for both classes)

```
pdp::partial(fit, "Dist_Water", type = "classification", which.class = "presence", prob = TRUE) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(class = "presence") %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows(.,
          pdp::partial(fit, "Dist_Water", type = "classification", which.class = "absence", prob = TRUE) %>%
              dplyr::mutate(class = "absence")) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x= Dist_Water, y = yhat, col = class)) +
    geom_line() +
    cowplot::theme_cowplot()
```